# извлечение членов пространства имён при документировании через doxygen

Tags: c++, namespace, doxygen

Нужно на странице группы в генерируемой doxygen'ом документации получить список всех членов этой группы, даже если они находятся в пространстве имён.
Например, мы определяем группу и добавляем в неё класс через @{ @}:

```
/*!
@defgroup test_group Example group
@{*/
    class some_class {};
/// @}
```

В данном случае всё в порядке, доксиген создаст страницу группы test_group, на которой будет искомый класс:

[image: группа с одним классом]

Но после добавления в код пространств имён доксиген начинает переносить их члены на отдельные страницы, например, результатом следующего фрагмента:

```
/*!
@defgroup test_group Example group
@{*/
namespace example_namespace {       
    class some_class {};
}
/// @}
```

Станут уже 2 страницы: страница группы (только с пространством example_namespace) и страница самого пространства, которая содержит классы, которые в нём находятся:
[image: навигация из 2х страниц]
В данном случае все члены пространства имён переносятся на новую страницу. Как можно избежать подобного?
Варианты:

// 1. заключение содержимого пространства в блок @{ @}:

```
    /// @defgroup test_group Example group        
    namespace example_namespace { 
        /*!
        @ingroup test_group 
        @{ */
        class some_class {};
        /// @}
    }
```

// 2. включение самого пространства в группу

```
    /// @defgroup test_group Example group
    
    /// @ingroup test_group 
    namespace example_namespace {
        class some_class {};
    }
```

Дают одинаковый результат, такой же как на втором изображении: страница группы, содержащая только namespace и отдельная страница пространства имён, на которой уже указано его содержимое.

Если прописать " @ingroup test_group " в описание **каждого** класса, то они добавляются корректно, но в проекте сотни классов, раскиданных по разным пространствам имён. Как можно выйти из подобной ситуации без тысяч ctrl+c - ctrl+v ?

Comment: Можно ли перевести это сообщение на английский и опубликовать его по адресу https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask? (Is it possible to translate this message into english and post it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask ?)

Comment: @albert я пытался задавать этот вопрос, но результата нет:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549759/how-to-make-doxygen-include-namespace-members-to-group-page

Answer (score 1):

Я делал таким образом:

```
    /**
 * \namespace FC
 * {@
 */
namespace FC {

/** @defgroup C
 * @{
 */

/**
  * @brief Структура
  */
typedef struct fcore_{
    struct {
        unsigned char s_b1, s_b2, s_b3, s_b4;
    } S_un_b;
} fcore;

/**
* @brief Класс
*/
class FCORE_API FИ
{
public:
char a;
}
…………
/** @} */ (здесь заканчивается группа)
}
/** @} */ (здесь заканчивается пространство имен)
```

Получается отдельно в пункте меню Пространства имен пространство FC, и отдельно  в пункте меню  Группы группа C, содержащая все, что указано. Каждый класс отдельно включать не надо при этом.